# Can't find the link to the image source CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I downloaded some code from CODE PEN. It comprised an HTML file, two css, one scss and two javascript files.

I'm trying to replace an image (the Twitter Icon) in the HTML but I can't seem to find where the link to the image is written in the text. I've tried searching in all the other files (css, js)
Here is section from the html file:

```
<div class="section" id="sect2">
<div class="anchor" id="anchor2"></div>
<div id="hiddenIcon">
<i class="icon-twitter"></i>
    </div>
<div id="twitter"  data-600="margin-top: -20%; opacity: 0" data-1000="margin-top: 0; opacity:1">
<i class="icon-twitter"></i>
</div>
<div class="explanation" data-850=" opacity: 0" data-900=" opacity:1">
<h2>Talks + Workshops + Panel Discussion</h2>
<p>Learn from and interact with world-class social entrepreneurs. Keynote speaker: <u> Christian Vanizette </u> (Founder of Makesense).</p>
  <a class="arrow" href="#anchor3"><i class="icon-sort-down"></i></a>
</div><!--/ explanation-->
```

Comment: I'd imagine it's the `background-image`, `background` of the empty `<i>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<i class='icon-twitter'></i>
```

This displays the icon.

Search in the CSS files for ".icon-twitter". You'll probably find something like this:

```
.icon-twitter
{
  background-image:URL('url/to/image.png');
  //The rest of the code
}
```

Comment: I've searched all the files, including the two css stylesheets. In one of the css stylesheets this is all that comes up: #twitter {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

Comment: @user3238800 Try searching for '#hiddenIcon i'. If this doesn't work use ctr+f to find any image extensions. I hope this is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="icon-twitter"></i>
```

Its not an image tag, but rather an icon rendered with CSS. Check your css files for this class in order to change it

Answer (score 0):

`<i class="icon-twitter"></i>` has a font inside it rendered by a css (by the content property).
You should change the style if you want to change this icon.